# C++11: Recursion in a stacked variadic struct (I get an linker error)

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I wanted to implement a template recursion algorithm where I forward two variadic parameters and decrement the variable `K`. 
I thought that the easiest approach is to stack two `struct`s definitions. However, I get a linker error if I try to make an debug output on a `constexpr`. A similar approach code seems to work if I just do it in a non-stacked struct.

```
: In function `void detail::L1<3ul, 4ul, 3ul, 2ul, 1ul>::L2<2ul, 3ul, 4ul, 5ul>::run<int, int, int, int>(int, int, int, int)':
: undefined reference to `detail::L1<3ul, 4ul, 3ul, 2ul, 1ul>::L2<2ul, 3ul, 4ul, 5ul>::dim_array'
: In function `void detail::L1<2ul, 4ul, 3ul, 2ul, 1ul>::L2<2ul, 3ul, 4ul, 5ul>::run<int, int, int, int>(int, int, int, int)':
: undefined reference to `detail::L1<2ul, 4ul, 3ul, 2ul, 1ul>::L2<2ul, 3ul, 4ul, 5ul>::dim_array'
: In function `void detail::L1<1ul, 4ul, 3ul, 2ul, 1ul>::L2<2ul, 3ul, 4ul, 5ul>::run<int, int, int, int>(int, int, int, int)':
: undefined reference to `detail::L1<1ul, 4ul, 3ul, 2ul, 1ul>::L2<2ul, 3ul, 4ul, 5ul>::dim_array'
```

Code

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

template <size_t K, std::size_t... IDs>
struct L1 {
    template <std::size_t... DIMS>
    struct L2 {
        static constexpr std::array<size_t, sizeof...(DIMS)> dim_array = {{DIMS...}};

        static void run() {
            constexpr size_t n = dim_array[K];

            for(int i = 0; i < sizeof...(DIMS); i++) {
                std::cout<<dim_array[i]<<" ";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;

            L1<K-1, IDs...>::template L2<DIMS...>::run();
        }
    };
};

template <std::size_t... IDs>
struct L1<0, IDs...> {
    template <std::size_t... DIMS>
    struct L2 {
        static constexpr std::array<size_t, sizeof...(DIMS)> dim_array = {{DIMS...}};
        static void run() {
        }
    };
};

int main() {
    L1<3, 4,3,2,1>::template L2<2,3,4,5>::run();
}
```

Works:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

template <std::size_t... DIMS> // Define dimensions of the ctrl point grid. E.g. 4x4x4
struct works {
  static void run() { 
    static constexpr std::array<size_t, sizeof...(DIMS)> dim_array = {{DIMS...}};
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof...(DIMS); i++) {
      std::cout<<dim_array[i]<<" ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
};

int main() {
    works<1,2,3>::run();
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: This is a minimal example. It is just one stacked recursive template. Do you have an idea how to make it smaller, if it works if non-stacked?

Comment: I am sure you have a `main` function, don't you?

Comment: Okay, I changed both examples to compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you have forgotten to add (outside the structs) the following lines

```
template <std::size_t K, std::size_t... IDs>
template <std::size_t ... DIMS>
constexpr std::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(DIMS)> 
      L1<K, IDs...>::L2<DIMS...>::dim_array;

template <std::size_t K, std::size_t... IDs>
template <std::size_t ... DIMS>
constexpr std::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(IDs)>
      L1<K, IDs...>::L2<DIMS...>::id_array;
```

I mean... you have declared `dim_array` and `id_array` but you haven't defined they.

p.s.: I have modified the tag of you question from c++11 to c++14 because, if you compile

```
constexpr size_t n = dim_array[K];
```

your compiling c++14 code (the `operator[]` in `std::array` is `constexpr` starting from c++14)

**-- EDIT --**

The OP

> Seems not to work, but if I move the definition of dim_array into the function it compiles :/

Sorry: I answered to you original question; you have modified it (deleting `id_array`) so you have to add only the definition of `dim_array`.

The following code is OK for me (OK... well... there are some warnings)

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

template <size_t K, std::size_t... IDs>
struct L1 {
    template <std::size_t... DIMS>
    struct L2 {
        static constexpr std::array<size_t, sizeof...(DIMS)> dim_array = {{DIMS...}};

        static void run() {
            constexpr size_t n = dim_array[K];

            for(int i = 0; i < sizeof...(DIMS); i++) {
                std::cout<<dim_array[i]<<" ";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;

            L1<K-1, IDs...>::template L2<DIMS...>::run();
        }
    };
};

template <std::size_t... IDs>
struct L1<0, IDs...> {
    template <std::size_t... DIMS>
    struct L2 {
        static constexpr std::array<size_t, sizeof...(DIMS)> dim_array = {{DIMS...}};
        static void run() {
        }
    };
};

template <std::size_t K, std::size_t... IDs>
template <std::size_t ... DIMS>
constexpr std::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(DIMS)> L1<K, IDs...>::L2<DIMS...>::dim_array;

int main() {
    L1<3, 4,3,2,1>::template L2<2,3,4,5>::run();
}
```

And, yes: if you move the definition of `dim_array` inside `run()`, it works. Because, in that case, the declaration is also the definition.

Comment: Seems not to work, but if I move the definition of dim_array into the function it compiles :/

Comment: Is there btw a better way to work with two variadics?

Comment: @dgrat - answer modified; about the better way to work with two variadics... I don't understand what you want to know (sorry: my English is very poor).

Comment: I guess you made a c&p mistake as the example is now identical with mine :)

Comment: @dgrat - D'ho! You're right: copy and paste error. Corrected.